# How to calculate Ocean heat content?

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray, ocean

I have a subsurface temperature data upto 300m oceanic depth (having irregular depth). And I want to calculate ocean heat content for 0-300m in Python. The cell area is being computed by CDO tool.

The formula is:

OHC = sea water density * Specific heat capacity * integrating the temperature over this depth.

I am able to write a code.

```py
#OHC Calculation  
def ocean_heat(Temperature,cell Area):  

   density = 1026 #kg/m^3

   c_p = 3990 #J/(kg K)
    
   heat = Temperature.sum(dim=['depth','lon','lat']) * density * c_p * cell Area
    
   return heat
```

But, the depth is not on same interval. So I think there is need to use weighted temperature. So if anyone can help to know the proper procedure to compute OHC. And if there is another sources or modules then please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to multiply each term by the difference in depths? Is the area a constant for each iteration, or is also a vector?  You'll need a separate vector for "cell depth" or "cell volume".  This function may by useful in calculating the differences in depth: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ediff1d.html   It also looks like you've got a space inside the variable "cell Area" which would be a syntax error.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please see the guide on [ask] and especially how to create a [mre]. As it currently stands, it's not clear to us whether you're asking a method question (what is the right scientific procedure?) which probably belongs on [Earth Science stack exchange](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or if its about how to implement a weighted average or sum of an xarray DataArray. If the latter, please help us understand more about what you've tried and where you're stuck, including replication data, all your code, and stack traces for any errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is a NetCDF file I suggest taking a look at the Xarray package. It is used to work with labeled multidimensional arrays. It is very popular in Earth Science.

Here is an example from Pangeo using Xarray to calculate ocean heat content:
https://gallery.pangeo.io/repos/NCAR/notebook-gallery/notebooks/Run-Anywhere/Ocean-Heat-Content/OHC_tutorial.html

The first part is about speeding up the computation with Dask. Task 8 is where they start calculating ocean heat content.